# Why do I sometimes not get credit for "Pink'd" when killing bosses?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that in order to get the Pink'd acheivement you need to have "***head, shoulder, feet, leg, hand, and torso equipment colored with Lovely Dye***", and I have of course done that - but I notice as I play through the game I sometimes get credit towards the acheivement for killing bosses, and other times I don't.  Am I doing something wrong?  I'd suspect it was bugged, but since I sometimes get credit it can't be completely broken (or at least that seems unlikely).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be possible that any followers/allies of yours actually deal the killing blow to the enemy, thereby taking the kill and achievement progress from you. It would seem like an arbitrary reason if not for the achievement that deals with letting your followers get kills on certain bosses, 'I'll Be Your Wingman'.

EDIT: It would appear that followers do not block achievement progress (if they get the kill) when you're in pink armor, however other players will. After the testing we both have done (same results as you had), it seems like this is pretty set in stone. Go solo, get achievement, win at life.

Comment: I tested this out, and I still got credit when my follower dealt the killing blow.  I think you are on the right track though.  I suspect the issue is that others in my party were not fully "Pink'd" when I wasn't getting credit.  I'll post back when I can confirm.

Comment: That would've been my next guess! I was assuming you were playing solo (as I do when I'm trying to grind up some of the more...inventive achievements), so the thought didn't cross my mind.

Comment: Instead, I was helping others and just grabbed the pink gear to make it worth helping.  I probably continued crushing lowbie bosses after they left, and hence got credit for a few bosses, but never the ones when they were present.  Would you consider editing your answer?  I'm happy to give you the check, but as is I think it's a little misleading.

Comment: Answer edited, thought it was better to add on instead of changing what was already said. I don't care about the check credit; just glad I could help/hope this helps other people!

Comment: After testing with a friend ( @agent86), we confirmed several things. 1. You or your pet/follower need to deal the killing blow, party members don't count. 2. You can still get credit with a party member, if you deal the killing blow.  Note: In our experiment, we were both wearing full pink gear.  We also removed class specific items, as I theorize (based on internet chatter) this could also block you - even if they are dyed pink.

Comment: @agent86 killed Diablo with a gollum, which was fun to watch.